# Procedure to count days between two dates

Tags: t-sql

Seems redundant, but I am trying to count rows in a temporary created table inside a procedure.

(Note: table is most likely coded wrong) The `@rows` variable is needed to be counted and should output the exact amount of days in a year from the `@StartDate` variable. (this is including leap years).

The table created should also `INSERT` date `VALUES` for each day for exactly a year after the `@StartDate` variable.

TEMPORARY TABLE required in this assignment. Sorry people, but that is what the teacher is asking for.

FYI: I'm a novice, and help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DateLookup
    @StartDate DATE,
    @Rows INT OUTPUT

AS
    DECLARE @countIndex INT
    DECLARE @yearDate DATE
    DECLARE @todaysDate DATE
    SET @yearDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1,@StartDate)
    SET @todaysDate = GETDATE()
    BEGIN

        CREATE TABLE #DateLookup
        (
        DateID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
        DateDescription DATE
        )

     WHILE (SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,@StartDate, @yearDate) FROM #DateLookup) <= 366   
     BEGIN
         SET @countIndex = @countIndex +1

        INSERT #DateLookup (DateDescription)
        VALUES (DAY(@todaysDate)+ @countIndex)

    END
    SET @Rows = (SELECT COUNT(DateDescription) FROM #DateLookup) 
END
GO


DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @Rows INT

SET @StartDate = '2012-05-06'
EXEC usp_DateLookup @StartDate, @Rows OUTPUT
PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@Rows)
```

Comment: Why do you need `#DateLookup` table? You are going to create this table every time you run this procedure. You have to drop it

Comment: Your procedure is full of issues, but you haven't said what your current problem is (errors? incorrect results?) or what you expect your procedure to do. You seem to want to count the number of days between a specific date and the same day one year later, but in that case you only need `DATEDIFF()` and `DATEADD()`, there is no need for temp tables or looping. If you can clarify your logic then someone may be able to help.

Comment: Yeah sorry, temp table required in this assignment. The output I am getting is '0'. It needs to be atleast 365

Comment: This is a digression, but when you turn in your work it would be very interesting for you to ask your teacher what he is trying to teach you with this exercise. He asked you to use two features (loops and temporary tables) that are completely unnecessary here and indeed one of them is highly discouraged in all SQL code (loops). Hopefully he wants you to experience first-hand how inefficient and awkward it is to program procedurally in SQL...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need `#DateLookup` table? You can get the number of days in a year as follows (Better to use as a function)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DateLookup
    @StartDate DATE,
    @Rows INT OUTPUT

AS
    --DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2012-05-06'
    select @Rows = datediff(day,@StartDate,dateadd(year,1,@StartDate))

END
GO;
```

As per your comment ( You need the temp table for the assignment), you could do it without a loop as below; [SQL-DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0e54/1)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DateLookup
    @StartDate DATE,
    @Rows INT OUTPUT

AS
    --DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2012-05-06'
    DECLARE @Rows INT = DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,dateadd(year,1,@StartDate))

    CREATE TABLE #DateLookup
    (
      DateID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
      DateDescription DATE
    )

    ;with Digits as (
    select Digit 
    from (
        values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), 
            (6), (7), (8), (9)) as t(Digit)),
    Numbers as (
        select u.Digit + t.Digit*10 +h.Digit*100  as Number
        from Digits u
        cross join Digits t
        cross join Digits h
    )
    insert into #DateLookup
    select  dateadd(day,Number+1,@StartDate) from Numbers where Number < @Rows 
    order by Number

END
GO;
```

Also you need a LOOP? Your `INSERT` fails since you trying to enter a number (`DAY(@todaysDate)+ @countIndex`) into `DATE` field

```
INSERT #DateLookup (DateDescription)
    VALUES ('this-should-be-a-valid-date')
```

Comment: do you have that table already created? and need to fill every time you run this procedure? You cannot create temp table every time you run this without checking its existence.

Comment: There will be no error because of the temp table. It exists only within the scope of the procedure and will be dropped when it exits. This is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191132(v=sql.105).aspx), but a trivial example shows it easily; you can run this procedure repeatedly with no errors: `create proc #p as create table #t (i int)`

Comment: @Pondlife, Okay thanks for that I forgot scope thing. Will update. But there is no use of it if it drops at the end of the scope again.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. But loop is also required haha

Comment: I have updated with some details, rest is for you to learn from the assignment.